# Generate a popup by clicking cells in a table?

Tags: popup

How can we generate a popup (with configurable size) by clicking on a html table cell? Every cell will have unique id, hence the popup needs to display unique content every time it shows up.

Thanks,
Navin

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using Javascript, jQuery or a plugin, e.g.: http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: Thanks @Julien, I was able to achieve this using Modal option in BootStrap.